# Why won't my JS file load?

Tags: javascript, html

using this code:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/hovermenus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to [load](http://pastebin.com/mANCGhef) this script

firebug is not showing this script as loaded, however, these scripts:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/salf_ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/date.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/datePicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

all load perfectly well. I have double, triple and quadruple checked the file is in the right directory.

Comment: What does the rendered html look like?

Comment: The only difference I can see if the charset attribute on the one that doesn't work. Have you tried removng that?

Comment: And when you go to `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/hovermenus.js` does the script show up?

Comment: anything in your `Error Console`? have you checked the `permissions` of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see these:
[Why doesn't ASP.NET (3.5) always load an external javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901916/why-doesnt-asp-net-3-5-always-load-an-external-javascript)

[Firebug doesn't load JavaScript files or stop execution on breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095453/firebug-doesnt-load-javascript-files-or-stop-execution-on-breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is with your file

Make sure the file `.../scripts/hovermenus.js` exists. Navigate there and copy paste the file name from there.

Could the script be in another directory? could it be `hoverMenus.js` or `hover.menus.js`.... etc.

If none of this works, try copying and renaming the file. See if you can load the renamed version. If you can't, it's something in the file.

Unrelated: You should declare your variables with `var` so you don't create a bunch of global variables attached to `window`.

Answer (score 0):

charset isnt a valid attribute for the script tag, try removing it

**EDIT**

Actually it is valid, try removing it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've closed all your script tags above the one you're trying to load.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem: same file would not load on other pages(master pages)

```
original: 

   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/scriptMob.js"></script>

fixed:    
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/scriptMob.js"></script>
```

only removed dots and first slash

Additionally you can check in firebug(HTML section), expand the reference line

```
    (+) <script src="../../Scripts/scriptMob.js" type="text/javascript">
```

to check whether browser actually reads the js file correctly.

the error message was saying:
[SqlException]: Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, shoving my head against a wall trying to figure it out. Turned out the js file had a syntax issue buried in it, something stupid that didn't show in my editor ... in this case it was a hanging 'var ' with nothing after it.  As soon as I deleted that, everything was copacetic.

So my recommendation if you run into this is what I did - remove all functions and add them back one by one until you find one that kills it.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, cant load script /js/search_ads.js It was problem in my adblock extension After renaming to search.js problem was disappearing